# How to remove SSL bindings using powershell

Tags: iis, powershell

I use `Remove-WebBinding -Port $Port -Protocol https` to remove a web binding. This removes the binding from the associated site but the binding continues to exist and I can find an entry under `IIS:\SslBindings` but not assigned to any site

If i try to assign any of these unused binding i get the error
**SSL binding for end point 0.0.0.0:38000 already exists.**

question is which cmdlet should I use to delete the binding or to remove the entry from IIS:\SslBinding ?

Regards,
Jeez

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What about using `Remove-Item` :

Example :

```
PS> dir IIS:\SslBindings

IP Address       Port Store            Sites
----------       ---- -----            -----
0.0.0.0          8172 MY
0.0.0.0          9000 My

PS> Remove-Item -path "IIS:\SslBindings\0.0.0.0!9000"
PS> dir IIS:\SslBindings

IP Address       Port Store            Sites
----------       ---- -----            -----
0.0.0.0          8172 MY
```

Comment: Thanks JPBlanc this does the job but is there any cmdlet defined in WebAdministration module that will do this ?

Answer (score 5):

Of course there is a WebAdministration cmdlet : Remove-WebBinding
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790591.aspx

Comment: I don't understand why this answer exists, or why anyone upvoted it.  In the question the poster says they are using Remove-WebBinding.

Answer (score 5):

[Use netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 to delete a SSL certificate binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http#delete-sslcert):
example:

```
$DelSsl = netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443
$DelSsl 
$Ssl = netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=$certhash appid=$appid
$Ssl
```